# Spring RabbitTemplate execute method visibility

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

`RabbitTemplate` has an `execute` method that is [public](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplate.html#execute-org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.ChannelCallback-), and another one that receives a `ConnectionFactory` but it is [private](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplate.java#L1922). I could understand that it is private if `ConnectionFactory` was not exposed, but it already has a `getConnectionFactory()` method.

I would like to decorate `execute` method behavior but cannot. Is there a reason I am not seeing for not making it protected so we can override it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you edit the question to explain exactly what you want to achieve?

I am not keen on exposing it because there would be nothing to stop a user from calling it with a completely unrelated connection factory (no guarantee that it was received from `getConnectionFactory()`).

While I wouldn't expect any problems with that, there might be some unintended side effects, particularly if the template is transactional, which could cause us some support pain when something weird happens.

Perhaps we can come up with some other way to get you what you need.

Comment: This is good enough of an answer for me, makes sense. I'll look for another way and post a new question if I get stuck, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I don't intend to sound patronizing (even though I am sure it sounds that way), but it's generally better to state the problem (along with a proposed solution, perhaps) rather than just the proposed solution.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, this is one of my poorly described questions, I'll make sure to describe the problem of my next question better for sure... I know this isn't particularly helpful to others, I just didn't feel comfortable discussing this in more details.